# I need to get the File name from the XML code which generated by Xsl:value of in XSL Form

Tags: xml, xslt

From `<xsl:value-of select="$CashFlowAttach" />` it will come XML Code contain data, from that value i need extract the filename from that {For eg: value could be `<p xmlns:Utils="cim:Utils"><a href="resources/Attachment/spend plan.123"><image border="0" width="89px" height="47px" src="resources/Content/images/CIMtrek_spend_plan_123.gif"></image></a></p>` } I need the Value is File name = spend plan.123 at last . Any condition is there to check like that in XSL Form

```
<xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="string-length($CashFlowAttach)!=0">
  <xsl:if test="not(contains($CashFlowAttach,'&lt;p xmlns:Utils=&quot;cim:Utils&quot;&gt;'))">
   <a>
    <xsl:attribute name="onclick">ajaxcallingForFileDownload('<xsl:value-of        select="$CashFlowAttach" />')  
    </xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:value-of select="$CashFlowAttach" />
   </a>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Do you need the "resources/Attachment/" part, or just the filename "spend plan.123"?

Comment: I need to have the file name only.

Comment: Value i have mentioned above For eg it is coming from database.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest adding this template to your XSLT:

```
  <xsl:template name="GetFileName">
    <xsl:param name="path" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($path, '/')">
        <xsl:call-template name="GetFileName">
          <xsl:with-param name="path"
                          select="substring-after($path, '/')" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$path"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

This template can be used to get the filename at the end of a path.  Then you would call it using something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="fileName">
  <xsl:call-template name="GetFileName">
     <xsl:with-param name="path"
      select="substring-before(substring-after($CashFlowAttach, 'a href=&quot;'), 
                                  '&quot;')" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```